# Converting a stand-alone Delphi-made .tlb file to .ridl

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, typelib

How does one convert a stand-alone .tlb file created in a pre-2009 version of Delphi to a .ridl file using Delphi 2010? .tlb files that are part of projects get automatically converted, but this particular file is not part of any project.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try using the tlibimp.exe utility located in C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\bin

```
tlibimp –I thetlbfile.tlb
```

Comment: It looks like we posted the answer at the same time :)

Comment: to note that in XE2 the above command fails and prints out the command syntax. using it like this "tlibimp /I thetlbfile.tlb" makes it work there too. (see the slash instead of the dash in front of the I parameter)